# Regex expression group not working as expected

Tags: regex

Newer versions of php let you declare arrays using javascript-like array syntax, like this:

`$arr = [$var1, $var2];`

For compatibility reasons, I want to convert that to older php style array syntax, which would be this

`$arr = array($var1, $var2);`

So I made a regex to find any expressions in between square brackets after an equal sign with 0 or 1 spaces after it, and it works, it looks like this:

`\=(\s){0,1}\[(.*?)+\]`

And replace the square brackets with the `array` delimiter, so

`[ //stuff ]` becomes
`array( //stuff)`

So using expression groups, I would think that `$0` would be the whole regex, `$1` would be the `(\s){0,1}`, and `$0` would be the `(.*?)+`, so replacing with this

`array\( $2 \)` should do the trick
**except $1 and $2 are both empty strings, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.**  I tried in Netbeans and Notepad++ with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `+` quantifier after the capturing parenthesis. If you remove that, everything should work. It's almost never a good idea to quantify a capturing group (and RegexBuddy will warn you sternly if you do).

```
=(\s?)\[(.*?)\]
```

**Explanation:**

`(.*?)` matches a string of any length, preferably the empty string. If you have the regex `\[(.*?)\]` and apply it to `[a]`, then the group will match `a`, as expected.

But see what happens if you use the regex `\[(.*?)+\]` instead:

- `\[` matches `[`.
- `(.*?)` matches the empty string before `a` and captures it.
- The `+` asks for at least one repetition, as many as possible, so let's do one:
- `(.*?)` matches the `a` and captures it, overwriting the previously matched `""`!
- Let's do another repetition!
- `(.*?)` matches the empty string before `]` and captures it, overwriting the previously matched `"a"`.
- `(.*?)` matches the `]` and captures it, overwriting the previously matched `""`.
- Whoops, end of string is reached, and we haven't matched `\]` yet. Back up.
- `(.*?)` matches the empty string before `]` and captures it, overwriting the previously matched `"]"`.
- `\]` matches `]`. Hurrah!

Group 1 now contains the empty string, Group 0 (or `$&` in JavaScript) contains `[a]`.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation...  `almost never a good idea to quantify a capturing group` Except in .NET if you are interested in capture collections (you know this of course but mentioning it in the comment for completion.)